# nginx how to get status of webservers on the backend?

Tags: nginx

HAProxy has a very nice status page showing me which webservers are up and which ones are down on the backend.  I am trying to debug some issues and need to know which servers nginx thinks are up and which ones it thinks are down.  Is there a web page or something that you can configure for nginx so I can just hit a url when I need this type of information?

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a couple of modules you may want to check out:

- https://github.com/anomalizer/ngx_upstream_status (displays status as seen by the worker serving the status page)
- https://github.com/yaoweibin/nginx_upstream_check_module (proactively checks status of upstream servers)
- https://github.com/cep21/healthcheck_nginx_upstreams (similar to the previous one but only supports HTTP 1.0 for status checks)
- http://nginx.localdomain.pl/wiki/UpstreamFair (load balancer with built-in status page)
- ...

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately this is almost impossible out of the box. vanila nginx has not global state for upstream by design so this information is local for every worker process.

Take a look at this module seems may be useful for you http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpHealthcheckModule

Answer (score 0):

A year late to this reply but ustats module for nginx looks pretty impressive:

https://code.google.com/p/ustats/

moved to github https://github.com/0xc0dec/ustats

Unfortunately doesn't seem maintained after 1.2 but might still work.

Found a maintained fork https://github.com/nginx-modules/ngx_ustats_module

1.7.2 patch still works against 1.7.4 perfectly

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a simple health check as Amazon ELB provides. Ability to add instances in an LB, have a health check mechanism to remove faulty instances.

So here were my options.

1. https://github.com/yaoweibin/nginx_upstream_check_module
2. https://github.com/openresty/lua-resty-upstream-healthcheck
3. Nginx also provides a passive health check for free. It does exactly what I want it to, no fancy monitoring, no weights, no fancy route check. It would ping the server and check for 200 status response. It would do it in round robin fashion.

   The fail_timeout parameter sets the time during which the specified number of failed attempts should happen and still consider the server unavailable. In other words, the server is unavailable for the interval set by fail_timeout.

   The max_fails parameter sets the number of failed attempts that should happen during the specified time to still consider the server unavailable.

   Eg:

   `upstream search {
   server 192.168.215.43:9200 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=10s;
   server 192.168.171.66:9200 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=10s;
   }`